# Create a nested menubar/sidebar having multiple children

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[Running code on Stackblitz is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6dchto?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

The requirement is to make every object clickable, and if it has child, then child objects under it should open below it, and so on upto last child.

I have been able to loop through objects in the list, but couldn't loop inside child of an object, and so on.

**Note: Cannot use any HTML/CSS/JS library, have to create from scratch.**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  itemList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Home",
    icon: 'home',
    child: [{
      id: 11,
      name: "Home1",
      icon: 'home',
      child: [{
        id: 111,
        name: "Home11",
        icon: 'home',
        child: []
      }]
    }, {
      id: 1111,
      name: "Home2",
      icon: 'home',
      child: []
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Facility Management",
    icon: 'fac-mgmt',
    child: []
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Engineering Services",
    icon: "engg-serv",
    child: []
  }];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  openChild(item: any, index) {
    console.log(item.name)
  }
}
```

```css
.text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.11px;
  color: #214796;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 48px 8px 0 8px;
}

li {
  width: 296px;
  height: 48px;
  background: var(--neutral-20) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i=index" id="{{item.id}}">
    <li>
      <a class="text active" (click)="openChild(item, i)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified and achieved by using a different component to display all levels of the menubar.
app.component.html

```
<menu *ngFor="let item of itemList" [item]="item"></menu>
```

Now manage the opening and closing of children in this `menu` component. To give a better experience, we are using a boolean variable `expanded` to toggle expand and collapse.

menu.component.html

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;color:#007db8;"(click)="onItemSelected(item)">
    {{item.name}}
</a>
<div *ngIf=" expanded">
    <menu *ngFor="let child of item.child" [item]="child">
    </menu>
</div>
```

menu.component.ts

```
 @Input() item;
 expanded: boolean = false;
 onItemSelected(item: any) {
 console.log("clicked");
 if (item.child && item.child.length) {
  this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  console.log("exp", this.expanded);
 }
}
```

This is the [working link of Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-shwyiz?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.ts).

[image]

PS: I have not added any angular material components as per your requirement. If its allowed, `mat-list-item` and `mat-sidenav` can be the best option here. Use this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu) to modify CSS if needed.